# java.lang.NullPointerException but object isn't null (I suppose)

Tags: java

My last project (and the biggest :)) is the Ping Pong game.
I'm trying to implement "AI", but I can't do this because of

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at main.Ball$1.run(Ball.java:25)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I think I've written whole code well, but there must be something wrong.

Main.java -
http://pastebin.com/nvHwQAFD

Ball.java -
http://pastebin.com/cgE5r5eW

Player.java - pastebin.com/7QeiNciz

Ai.java - pastebin.com/xsGhJ7Zb (only two hyperlinks, spam prevention)

The code isn't written in good style and I hope you won't go (get?) blind :)

Greetings,
Adrian

Comment: Please paste the specific parts of the code that are having problems in the question.  We're not going to go reading through your entire code base.

Comment: Wow, having a variable of type `Player` called `p` and a variable of type `Rectangle` called `player` feels like a recipe for disaster. I would personally try to restructure your code before doing anything else.

Comment: As well as that, please format the code consistently too - in the Ball class for instance your brackets and indentation are all over the place.

Comment: Instead of supposing, you can try checking whether they are actually null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got a race condition.

When you call the `Ball` constructor, that immediately calls `movement()` which schedules the code which is problematic (admittedly in a different thread). All of this happens in the middle of the `Main` constructor *before* `Main.player` has been assigned. So in the line of `movement()` here:

```
if(main.player.intersects(main.ball) && hitP == false){
```

... `main.player` is still null if the timer thread starts quickly enough, so the `main.player.intersects` call throws the exception. (`main.ball` is also null, but that doesn't *actually* cause the problem you're seeing. It's still an issue though.)

A few lessons to learn:

- Don't do too much in a constructor
- Ideally, try to avoid creating this sort of cyclical reference, or if you *have* to have one, make sure everything's initialized before you start doing real work
- Make your class names more meaningful: `Main` is fine as *just* an entry point to a program, but creating an *object* of type `Main` sounds very suspicious to me. What *is* a `Main`? How would you describe it?
- Don't abuse inheritance - there's no reason why `Ball` should extend `Thread` (you say `implements Runnable` but you don't provide a `run()` method yourself in `Ball`)
- Avoid comparisons with `true` or `false` - write `if (foo)` instead of `if (foo == true)` and `if (!foo)` instead of `if (foo == false)`
- Make your variable names meaningful - as per my comment earlier, calling a `Rectangle` variable `player` in the same class that you have a `Player` variable called `p` is asking for trouble
- Make all your variables private, exposing them through properties *if you need to*. (Don't expose them unless you really *do* need to though)
- Indentation is important - indenting your code properly makes it much easier to read
- Until you're *really* comfortable with the basics of the language, avoid threading - it's hard, and can introduce all kinds of subtle problems

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I did what you said and now I'm getting next error:
http://pastebin.com/2aFVkQ6e

Comment: @AdrianMarszałek: It's not a good idea to try to just tackle one little problem at a time, telling us each problem and waiting for us to fix them. You should look through all the suggestions in my answer and others, take a step back, and probably start from scratch with a better design.

Comment: Jon Skeet, thank you, I'm going to try by myself and if I won't be able to do it I'll ask again.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you call `ball.movement()` on line 17 before assigning `main` a non-null value on line 18.

Answer (score 0):

This line: `player = new Rectangle(p.getX(), p.getY(), 10, 50);` in Main line 18 has to go before `b = new Ball(this);` in Main line 15. otherwise player is null when you call movement.